# jquery slide toggle - affects all on the page

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view with a list of a content type and using drupal behaviors and jquery toggle, I trying to toggle some content when the user clicks a div. The only problem is that it's affecting all the divs and they're all toggling open, I'd just like the one they clicked to open.

Here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
 Drupal.behaviors.myToggle = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
  $('.views-row').find('.views-field-field-mp3').hide();

    $('.mp3-toggle', context).click(function() {
     $('.views-field-field-mp3').slideToggle();
    });
  }
 };
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried return false and a couple of other things, though none seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where in your document is `.mp3-toggle` in relation to `.views-field-field-mp3`?

Comment: Should be able to change `$('.views-field-field-mp3').slideToggle();` to `$(this).parents('.views-row').find('.views-field-field-mp3').slideToggle();` if `.mp3-toggle` is within the views row

Comment: .mp3-toggle is within a views-row but not the same, so it should be in the same views row?

Comment: Thanks that appears to work now! Submit your comment as the answer and I'll mark as the correct an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make use of the `this` keyword inside your click function:

```
 Drupal.behaviors.myToggle = {
   attach: function(context, settings) {
     $('.views-row').find('.views-field-field-mp3').hide();

     $('.mp3-toggle', context).click(function() {
       $(this).parents('.views-row').find('.views-field-field-mp3').slideToggle();
     });
   }
 };
```